# From Logstash log4j input to beats

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, log4j, logstash, filebeat

Please, I was using **log4j** input of logstash, it was allowing me to **skip log parsing** (grok ...).

```
`input {
   log4j {
      mode => "server"
      host => "0.0.0.0"
      port => 8090
     }
   }`
```

Elastic now, in version [5.4.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-log4j.html), is tagging this input as ***deprecated***, and the alternative now is **filebeats**, which listen on log files directly.

The problem is that you need to parse your log files again via **grok filter**...is there any possible way to use beats for log4j without parsing log lines again, exactly like the old log4j socketAppender ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log4j [socket appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) does not use a layout. It sends the data in a structured format such that grok is not required.

To achieve a similar result you could configure log4j to write the data to log files in a structured format. This is commonly done with the [JSON layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout). So configure your app's log4j settings to write JSON events to a file.

Then once you have your logs in a structured format you can configure Filebeat to read the logs, decode the JSON data, and forward the events to Logstash or Elasticsearch.

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/myapp/output*.json
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.message_key: message
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this approach will generate an unnecessary additional log...

Comment: True, but there is a benefit in that the log file acts like a buffer. If Logstash goes down no logs are lost. The SocketAppender drops logs when Logstash is down.

Comment: You're right, I think the idea of using json log file is pretty smart, thank you, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logstash-logback-encoder`, it provides a `LogstashSocketAppender`, which implement SocketAppender, and using RSysLog to send log in json format to elasticsearch.